# Camera Tracking - How to Reconstruct LocRotScale Marker To Empty?

Tags: tracking, marker

I tracked a bit of video footage with a LocRotScale marker and tried to Reconstruct it as an empty but the empty doesn't have the rotating and scaling data.
Now my Question:
Is it possible (and when yes how) to export a LocRotScale marker to an empty with rotation and scale?

Answer (score 0):

Select your empty. Press F3 or spacebar for "SEARCH", type: "bake animation". Select Rotation, Scaling, etc.. Leave everything at default. Press OK.
In a new workspace window, switch to GRAPH EDITOR (shift F6). Select in your outliner the recently baked empty (if it's not already selected), you should open the eye icion in the graph editor, and find the channels you're interested in (rotationXYZ, and ScaleXYZ) now they should contain baked data.

From your question is not cleared if you did the tracking using blender tools of if you're importing it from another software. But at leas if you're inside blender, the previous described procedure should get data into your empty to track or follow.

Comment: Yes I tracked the data with blender, but I can't find the option "bake animation" I tried "Bake action" instead but it didn't work.
Any idea?